# Штрих код на php

Tags: php, barcode

Как сделать штрих код на php? А именно с цифрами, то есть на сайте после заполнения формы, появляется форма заказа со штрих кодом, и каждый раз после заполнения формы пользователем, цифры в штрих коде должны меняться. Пример:

[image: o]

Answer (score 1):

Используйте библиотеку [BarCode PHP](https://www.barcodebakery.com/en)

```
require_once('class/BCGFontFile.php');
require_once('class/BCGColor.php');
require_once('class/BCGDrawing.php');

require_once('class/BCGcode128.barcode.php');

header('Content-Type: image/png');

$color_white = new BCGColor(255, 255, 255);

$code = new BCGcode128();
$code->parse('HELLO');

$drawing = new BCGDrawing('', $color_white);
$drawing->setBarcode($code);

$drawing->draw();
$drawing->finish(BCGDrawing::IMG_FORMAT_PNG);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: неужели нет бесплатных библиотек?

Comment: есть и бесплатные https://github.com/picqer/php-barcode-generator